# Magento 2 Allocation of JIT memory failed, PCRE JIT

Tags: magento2, php

We use Magento 2.4.2 p2
We see in our log the following.

PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Allocation of JIT memory failed, PCRE JIT will be disabled. This is likely caused by security restrictions. Either grant PHP permission to allocate executable memory, or set pcre.jit=0 in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php on line 181

So I checked directorylist.php and do not get how to do this.

I asked my hoster to solve it. After days all they come up with is to sell me an upgrade...
So if anyone has any clues on solving this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has posted an Answer for you at URL

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Hosting-Performance/Magento-2-Allocation-of-JIT-memory-failed-PCRE-JIT/m-p/505988

Try it and let us know if it works, please.  Thank You and Happy Holidays.